# Assign Separate Port to One Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have this CI web application which serves both admin/client. The admin section is controlled by `application/controllers/admin.php`, while client section is controlled  by `application/controllers/client.php`.

I listened `port 1234` in Apache server, so that this whole application can be accessed by going to `127.0.0.1:1234`. But this is not what I want.

I would like to access to client section by going to `127.0.0.1:1234`, while accessing admin section by referring to `127.0.0.1:3333`. I tried to google it, ending with nothing.

My question is: Is it possible to do so? Or should I just deliver one CI application to serve client section, and another for admin section?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to use **virtual host** if you are using apache server see this **http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html**

Comment: Sure I use `virtual host` to set things up. That's what I asked. I know how to use different `virtual host` for different directory, but I don't know how to use it for different files, that is controllers I meant in CodeIgniter.